# How do I delete a realm?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms

I made a free realm, but I can't go on Minecraft PE because the month I paid for is up and I cannot pay for another month, so how do I get into Minecraft?

Comment: Your title is misleading, you want to delete a realm or you want to get into Minecraft? Or you want to get into Minecraft so you can delete a realm? Also, what edition are you running android, ios, PC?

Comment: May I have a Screenshot of how you are unable to get into Minecraft? What version of Minecraft? Like how artista_sin_nombre said, you may need to clarify your question. Is Minecraft kicking you out? Currently I am unable to answer!